# Why sequelize is not creating all columns in the table for postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, model, sequelize.js

I am creating a database module for my blog. I am using nodejs and sequelize module for this. The database I am using is Postgresql.

This is the sequelize initialization.

```
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

// Creating a singletone
let sequelize = null

module.exports = function setupDatabase (config) {
  if (!sequelize) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config)
  }

  return sequelize
}
```

The singleton is to evaluate if a previus instance of sequelize was already created.

And then I have an script configuration:

```
'use strict'

const debug = require('debug')('diesanromero:db:setup')
const inquirer = require('inquirer')
const chalk = require('chalk')

const db = require('./')

const prompt = inquirer.createPromptModule()

async function setup () {
  const answer = await prompt([
    {
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'setup',
      message: 'This will destroy your database, are you sure?'
    }
  ])

  if (!answer.setup) {
    return console.log('Nothing happend :)')
  }

  const config = {
    database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'blog',
    username: process.env.DB_USER || 'user',
    password: process.env.DB_PASS || 'password',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: s => debug(s),
    setup: true
  }

  await db(config).catch(handleFatalError)

  console.log('Success!')
  process.exit(0)
}

function handleFatalError (err) {
  console.error(`${chalk.red('[Fatal Error]')} ${err.message}`)
  console.error(err.stack)
  process.exit(1)
}

setup()
```

That is the script that creates the database, using the previous configuration.
Apparently all of this works fine. The database connects successfully. Then I have three models.

**article.js**

```
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const setupDatabase = require('../lib/db')

module.exports = function setupArticleModel (config) {
  const sequelize = setupDatabase(config)

  const stringRequired = {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }

  const numberDefault = {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    default: 0
  }

  return sequelize.define('article', {
    title: stringRequired,
    slug: stringRequired,
    description: stringRequired,
    content: stringRequired,
    likes: numberDefault,
    shares: numberDefault
  })
}
```

**user.js**

```
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const setupDatabase = require('../lib/db')

module.exports = function setupAuthModel (config) {
  const sequelize = setupDatabase(config)

  const stringRequired = {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }

  return sequelize.define('user', {
    name: stringRequired,
    username: stringRequired,
    email: stringRequired
  })
}
```

**auth.js**

```
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const setupDatabase = require('../lib/db')

module.exports = function setupUserModel (config) {
  const sequelize = setupDatabase(config)

  const stringRequired = {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }

  return sequelize.define('auth', {
    salt: stringRequired,
    hash: stringRequired,
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  })
}
```

And then my main file **index.js**

```
'use strict'

const defaults = require('defaults')

const setupDatabase = require('./lib/db')
const setupUserModel = require('./models/user')
const setupArticleModel = require('./models/article')

module.exports = async function (config) {
  config = defaults(config, {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    },
    query: {
      raw: true
    }
  })

  const sequelize = setupDatabase(config)
  const UserModel = setupUserModel(config)
  const AuthModel = setupAuthModel(config)
  const ArticleModel = setupArticleModel(config)

  UserModel.hasMany(ArticleModel)
  UserModel.hasOne(AuthModel)
  ArticleModel.belongsTo(UserModel)
  AuthModel.belongsTo(UserModel)

  await sequelize.authenticate()

  if (config.setup) {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  }

  const User = {}
  const Auth = {}
  const Article = {}

  return {
    User,
    Auth,
    Article
  }
}
```

This main file connects with **sequelize.authentication** successfully, and then performs migrations. Note that the User model has a 1 to 1 relationship with the Authentication model. Then the User model has a 1 to many relationship with the Article model.

It happens that the ORM does not create all the columns in the respective tables. Some if created, others not.

Comment: Try to `sync()` all models after they have been defined. Your sync is wrapped in if condition, not clear if is it called?

Comment: @elbik Hello. Thanks. How do i do it? Do I add the .sync () method to the model?